# Bitcoin logo license and can i use it?

Tags: bitcoin-logo

Can i use Bitcoin sign to create logo? I can not find any resource that says it's not protected. For example http://localbitcoins.com/ uses Bitcoin sign in they logo. 
I heard it's licensed with CC licence, but not sure.

Maybe someone know's this?

Answer (score 1):

The images in the [original thread are broken](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1631.0), but the text states that poster on bitcointalk placed the work in the public domain, i.e. the most permissive CC license. Prior to this the logo with "BC" was openly licensed by its inclusion in the Bitcoin source code.